# How to create many bounded types without duplicating code in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, bounded-types

For a project, I’ve created a type based on Int which throws an error whenever the program tries to use a value beyond limits ([0..127] in my case). The code below does this and it works for me.

Is it possible in Haskell to create a second bounded type (say [0..255] for example) without duplicating this code ?

Thanks for your answers

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
module Minitel.Type.MNatural (MNat, mnat, fromMNat) where

-- | The MNat type. The constructor is hidden.
newtype MNat = MakeMNat Int deriving (Real, Eq, Ord, Show)

-- | MNat is a bounded type
instance Bounded MNat where
    minBound = MakeMNat 0
    maxBound = MakeMNat 127

-- | Converts an Int into an MNat
mnat :: Int -> MNat
mnat x | loLimit <= x && x <= hiLimit = MakeMNat x
       | otherwise = error "Number out of bounds"
       where loLimit = fromIntegral (minBound :: MNat)
             hiLimit = fromIntegral (maxBound :: MNat)

-- | Converts an MNat into an Int
fromMNat :: MNat -> Int
fromMNat (MakeMNat i) = i

-- | Converts an Int binary function returning Int to a MNat binary function
--   returning an MNat
mfnat :: (Int -> Int) -> (MNat -> MNat)
mfnat f = mnat . f . fromMNat

mfnat2 :: (Int -> Int -> Int) -> (MNat -> MNat -> MNat)
mfnat2 f x y = mnat $ f (fromMNat x) (fromMNat y)

-- | You can do additions, substractions and multiplication with MNat
instance Num MNat where
    fromInteger = mnat . fromIntegral
    (+)         = mfnat2 (+)
    (-)         = mfnat2 (-)
    (*)         = mfnat2 (*)
    abs         = mfnat abs
    signum      = mfnat signum

-- | Allows to use toInteger with MNat
instance Integral MNat where
    quotRem x y = (fromInteger $ quot x' y', fromInteger $ rem x' y')
                  where (x', y') = (toInteger x, toInteger y)
    toInteger   = toInteger . fromMNat

-- | Allows to generate lists
instance Enum MNat where
    toEnum      = mnat
    fromEnum    = fromMNat
```

Note:

- performance is not a matter here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it in GHC 7.8 using type-level literals:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, PolyKinds, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module SO26723035 where

import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Proxy

newtype MNat (n :: Nat) = MakeMNat Int deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

instance KnownNat n => Bounded (MNat n) where
  minBound = MakeMNat 0
  maxBound = MakeMNat . fromInteger $ natVal (Proxy :: Proxy n)
```

```
ghci> maxBound :: MNat 5
MakeMNat 5
```

You can use type synonyms to fix individual types. The rest of your code compiles fine with this polymorphic `MNat` with mechanical changes. You have to add the `KnownNat` context everywhere and use `ScopedTypeVariables` in `mnat`.