# How to create Bounded instance based on runtime values?

Tags: haskell, matrix, types, typeclass, dependent-type

I've been playing with O'Connor's [matrix](http://r6.ca/blog/20110808T035622Z.html) implementation based on *-semirings, allowing very neat solutions for graph algorithms:

```
import Data.Array
newtype Matrix i e = Matrix (Array (i,i) e)

matrix :: (Ix i, Bounded i) => ((i,i) -> e) -> Matrix i e
matrix f = Matrix . listArray (minBound, maxBound) . map f $ entireRange
```

However, I'd like to read in adjacency matrices of arbitrary sizes from files in the outside world, so  having an enumerated type that the matrix is indexed on (like `Matrix Node :: Matrix Node2 (Maybe Integer)` from the same paper) doesn't really work for me.

My first thought was something like

```
toMatrix :: [[a]] -> Matrix Int a
toMatrix list = Matrix (listArray ((0,0),(l-1,l-1)) $ concat list)
  where l = length list
```

but of course this doesn't work either: trying to actually use this matrix blows up when various typeclass instances try to access index `(minBound :: Int, minBound :: Int)`.

Parameterizing the matrix type with a size like

```
newtype Matrix i e = Matrix i (Array (i,i) e)
```

doesn't quite work either: although I can change the `matrix` function to build matrices this way, now I have trouble writing `pure` for the `Applicative (Matrix i e)` instance or `one` for the `Semiring (Matrix i e)` instance, as the correct `one :: Matrix i e` depends on the size of the matrices in context.

Conceptually, I can think of two ways out of this:

1. Define a new `BoundedInt` type with a  `Bounded` instance that can be set at runtime when we know the size of the array, or
2. Find a way to declare instances of `Applicative (Matrix i e)` parameterized on the size of the matrix.

But I don't know how to implement either of these, and searches around the subject seem to turn up gnarly complicated things. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26723035/how-to-create-many-bounded-types-without-duplicating-code-in-haskell) question also looks relevant, but I don't think it solves the problem (though it would let me use the `Bounded i` constructor on matrices of fixed `Int` size).

What's the simplest solution here? Is there one without having to learn how to use the singleton library/some kind of dependent typing?

Comment: The simplest solution is not to implement `Applicative`; invent new function names that take your extra size parameters. (Whether you stuff those functions in a class or not depends on your needs.) But depending on what library operations are already available for things that support `Applicative` this may be painful... you'll know more than we will about whether that's a non-starter or not. What do you think?

Comment: Good point! Yes, splitting out variant methods from `Applicative`, `Semiring`, and `StarSemiring` is certainly an option, though I think a moderately painful and inelegant one. I'll keep this as a backup option depending on the other answers.

Comment: https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/pub/hasochism.pdf

Comment: I'm unclear on what you're trying to do. Do you want static bounds checking? (If so see _Hasochism_ as linked by @leftaroundabout.) Or do you want a way to dynamically build type class dictionaries? (If so I'll happily write you an answer about `reflection`.) They're very different requirements!

Comment: I think the ideas in _Hasochism_ are probably sufficient, but I still need a bit of hand-holding, I'm afraid — I can't quite get the right combination of Nattys and constraints and datatype declarations. Using @pigworker's `data Matrix :: (Nat,Nat) -> * -> * where Mat :: {unMat :: Vec h (Vec w a)} -> Matrix '(w,h) a`:

What does the `Applicative` instance look like, for example?
If I want to define a type synonym like `type AdjMat = Matrix Int (Tropical Double)` from O'Connor, can I?
What's the equivalent `toMatrix :: NATTY n => [[a]] -> Matrix (Pair n n) a`?
Thanks!

Comment: Another thought: can you get away with `data Matrix i e = Pure e | Matrix (Array (i,i) e)`?

Comment: @DanielWagner No, that's not enough because of `Semiring`'s `one ::  Matrix i e`, which in the `Bounded` version is implemented `one = buildMatrix (\(i,j) -> if i == j then one else zero)`. (If I used your idea from above, `buildMatrix` would be parameterized by size, so `oneM :: (A.Ix i, Enum i, Num i, Semiring e) => i -> Matrix i e` instead.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote a long answer about *[Hasochism](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/pub/hasochism.pdf)*'s `Matrix`'s `Applicative` instance, using finite sets as index types, but it's probably overkill for what you wanted, not to mention less efficient than the `Array`-based code in the blog post.

Your problem stems from the fact that various operations in the blog post's code assume that the `Bounded` instance for the matrix's index type is *covering*, in the sense that every value within the bounds will have a corresponding element in the matrix. The core assumption seems to be that the size of the matrix is known statically.

The simplest way to fix this would be to make an adjustment to the `Matrix` type, so that it carries its size around with it. You still have to do all your bounds checking dynamically, but I think that's a fairly good trade-off compared to the weightiness of the Hasochism approach.

```
-- Bounded as an explicit (minBound, maxBound) tuple
type Bounds i = (i, i)
data Matrix i e = Matrix { getBounds :: Bounds i, getMatrix :: Array (Edge i) e }

entireRange :: Ix i => Bounds i -> [i]
entireRange b = range b

matrix :: Ix i => Bounds i -> (Edge i -> e) -> Matrix i e
matrix bounds f = Matrix bounds $ listArray bounds $ map f $ entireRange bounds
```

This gets stuck, however, when you need to construct a matrix in a type class instance. You can't abstract instances over runtime values: the only thing valid to the left of the `=>` in an instance declaration is another type class constraint. In a declaration like

```
instance Bounded i => Applicative (Matrix i) where
    pure x = matrix (const x)
    (<*>) = -- ...
```

we have no choice than to pass the bounds statically in an instance dictionary because the type of `pure` doesn't allow us to pass explicit configuration data. [This restriction has its ups and downs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hIZxTQP1ifo), but right now it's a definite downer: the fix is to rip all of the classiness out of your code altogether.

---

Good news, though: you can emulate this explicit dictionary-passing style using the crazy [`reflection`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection) library, which does evil, magical things to push runtime values into typeclass dictionaries. It's scary stuff, but it does work, and it's safe.

It all happens in the [`reify`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection-2.1.2/docs/Data-Reflection.html#v:reify) and [`reflect`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection-2.1.2/docs/Data-Reflection.html#v:reflect) combinators. `reify` takes a runtime value and a block of code with a constraint depending on the availability of that value and plugs them in to one another. Calls to `reflect` inside the block return the value that was passed to `reify` outside it.

```
needsAnInt :: Reifies s Int => Proxy s -> IO ()
needsAnInt p = print (reflect p + 1)

example1 :: IO ()
example1 = reify 3 (\p -> needsAnInt p)  -- prints 4
example2 :: IO ()
example2 = reify 5 (\p -> needsAnInt p)  -- prints 6
```

Take a moment to reflect (ha ha) on how weird this is. Usually there's only one class dictionary in scope for each type (overlapping instances notwithstanding). `Proxy` has only one value (`data Proxy a = Proxy`), so how can `reflect` tell two proxies apart, to return different values each time?

Anyway, what's the point of this? Instances can't depend on runtime values, but they can depend on other instances. `reflection` gives us the tools to turn a runtime value into an instance dictionary, so this allows us to build instances which depend dynamically on runtime values!

In this case, we're building an instance of `Bounded`. We need a `newtype`, to make an instance which doesn't overlap with any others:

```
-- in this case it's fine to just lift the Ix instance from the underlying type
newtype B s i = B i deriving (Eq, Ord, Ix)
```

Clearly `B` can be an instance of `Bounded` if `i` is - it can get `minBound` and `maxBound` from `i`'s instance - but we want to get them from a `Reifies` context. In other words, the runtime value we'll be stuffing into the `Reifies` dictionary will be a pair of `i`s.

```
instance Reifies s (i, i) => Bounded (B s i) where
    minBound = B $ fst $ reflect (Proxy :: Proxy s)
    maxBound = B $ snd $ reflect (Proxy :: Proxy s)
```

I'm using `ScopedTypeVariables` crucially to come up with `Proxy` values of the correct type.

Now you can write perfectly ordinary code which uses a `Bounded` context (even if that context arises due to some other instance), and invoke it with a dynamically built `Bounded` dictionary using `reify`.

```
entireRange :: (Ix i, Bounded i) => [i]
entireRange = range (minBound, maxBound)

example3 :: IO ()
example3 = reify (3, 6) myComputation
    where myComputation :: forall s. Bounded (B s Int) => Proxy s -> IO ()
          myComputation p = print $ map unB (entireRange :: [B s Int])

ghci> example3
[3,4,5,6]
```

Um, yeah. `reflection` can be tricky to use. At the end of the day, it's probably simpler just to not bother with classes.

Comment: Thanks for a very detailed answer. I think it's clear how to progress for now, and what I can read to understand this stuff better latter…

Comment: This is what unlocked my issue: _The simplest way to fix this would be to make an adjustment to the `Matrix` type, so that it carries its size around with it._

Answer (score 2):

Today's a bank holiday here in the UK, so I had time to finish that answer about statically sized matrices. I wouldn't necessarily recommend doing this in production - even leaving aside how silly the code is, this is a *terrible* representation of matrices if you want to do efficient linear algebra on real hardware - but it's kinda fun to mess around with.

From [*Hasochism*](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/pub/hasochism.pdf):

```
-- Natural numbers and their singletons in explicit and implicit varieties
data Nat = Z | S Nat  -- page 2 of the paper
intToNat :: Int -> Maybe Nat  -- paraphrased from page 10
intToNat n
    | n < 0     = Nothing
    | n == 0    = Just Z
    | otherwise = S <$> intToNat (n-1)
data Natty n where  -- page 2
    Zy :: Natty Z
    Sy :: Natty n -> Natty (S n)
-- page 3
class NATTY n where
    natty :: Natty n
instance NATTY Z where
    natty = Zy
instance NATTY n => NATTY (S n) where
    natty = Sy natty

-- turn an explicit Natty into an implicit one
natter :: Natty n -> (NATTY n => r) -> r  -- page 4
natter Zy r = r
natter (Sy n) r = natter n r

-- vectors, matrices in row-major order
data Vec n a where  -- page 2
    V0 :: Vec Z a
    (:>) :: a -> Vec n a -> Vec (S n) a
newtype Mat w h a = Mat { unMat :: Vec h (Vec w a) }  -- page 4

-- vector addition, in the form of an Applicative instance
vcopies :: Natty n -> a -> Vec n a  -- page 4
vcopies Zy x = V0
vcopies (Sy n) x =  :> vcopies n x
vapp :: Vec n (a -> b) -> Vec n a -> Vec n b  -- page 4
vapp V0 V0 = V0
vapp (f :> fs) (x :> xs) = f x :> vapp fs xs
instance NATTY n => Applicative (Vec n) where  -- page 4
    pure = vcopies natty
    (<*>) = vapp

-- iterating vectors
instance Traversable (Vec n) where  -- page 4
    traverse f V0 = pure V0
    traverse f (x :> xs) = liftA2 (:>) (f x) (traverse f xs)
instance Foldable (Vec n) where  -- page 4
    foldMap = foldMapDefault
instance Functor (Vec n) where  -- page 4
    fmap = fmapDefault

transpose :: NATTY w => Mat w h a -> Mat h w a  -- page 4
transpose = Mat . sequenceA . unMat
```

I've taken the liberty of renaming the authors' `Matrix` type to `Mat`, rearranging its type arguments, and changing it from a GADT to a newtype. Forgive me for skipping over the explanation of the above - the paper does a better job than I could, and I want to get to the part where I answer your question.

---

`Mat w h` is an `h`-vector of `w`-vectors. It's the [type-level composition](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html#t:Compose) of two `Vec` functors. Its `Applicative` instance, which implements matrix addition, reflects that structure,

```
instance (NATTY w, NATTY h) => Applicative (Mat w h) where
    pure = Mat . pure . pure
    Mat fss <*> Mat xss = Mat $ liftA2 (<*>) fss xss
```

as does its `Traversable` instance.

```
instance Traversable (Mat w h) where
    traverse f = fmap Mat . traverse (traverse f) . unMat
instance Foldable (Mat w h) where
    foldMap = foldMapDefault
instance Functor (Mat w h) where
    fmap = fmapDefault
```

We also need a bit of equipment to work with indexes of vectors. To identify a particular element in an `n`-vector, you have to give a number less than `n`.

```
data Fin n where
    FZ :: Fin (S n)
    FS :: Fin n -> Fin (S n)
```

The type `Fin n` has exactly `n` elements, so `Fin` is the family of *finite sets*. A value of type `Fin n` is structurally a natural number less then `n` (compare `FS FZ` with `S Z`), so `FS FZ :: Fin (S (S Z))`, or `FS FZ :: Fin (S (S (S Z)))`, but `FS FZ :: Fin (S Z)` will fail to type check.

Here's a higher order function which builds a vector containing all the possible results of its argument.

```
tabulate :: Natty n -> (Fin n -> a) -> Vec n a
tabulate Zy f = V0
tabulate (Sy n) f = f FZ :> tabulate n (f . FS)
```

---

Now we can start working with semirings. Taking the dot product of two vectors involves multiplying their elements and then summing the result.

```
dot :: Semiring a => Vec n a -> Vec n a -> a
dot xs ys = foldr (<+>) zero $ vapp (fmap (<.>) xs) ys
```

Here's a vector which is `zero` everywhere except the specified index.

```
oneAt :: Semiring a => Natty n -> Fin n -> Vec n a
oneAt (Sy n) FZ = one :> vcopies n zero
oneAt (Sy n) (FS f) = zero :> oneAt n f
```

We'll use `oneAt` and `tabulate` to make an identity matrix.

```
type Square n = Mat n n

identity :: Semiring a => Natty n -> Square n a
identity n = Mat $ tabulate n (oneAt n)

ghci> identity (Sy (Sy Zy)) :: Square (S (S Z)) Int
Mat {unMat = (1 :> (0 :> V0)) :> ((0 :> (1 :> V0)) :> V0)}
-- ┌      ┐
-- │ 1, 0 │
-- │ 0, 1 │
-- └      ┘
```

And `transpose` comes in useful for matrix multiplication.

```
mul :: (NATTY w, Semiring a) => Mat r h a -> Mat w r a -> Mat w h a
mul m n =
    let mRows = unMat m
        nCols = unMat $ transpose n
    in Mat $ fmap (\r -> dot r <$> nCols) mRows

ghci> let m = Mat $ (1 :> 2 :> V0) :> (3 :> 4 :> V0) :> V0 :: Square (S (S Z)) Int in mul m m
Mat {unMat = (7 :> (10 :> V0)) :> ((15 :> (22 :> V0)) :> V0)}
-- ┌      ┐2   ┌        ┐
-- │ 1, 2 │  = │  7, 10 │
-- │ 3, 4 │    │ 15, 22 │
-- └      ┘    └        ┘
```

So that's the `Semiring` instance for square matrices sorted. Phew!

```
instance (NATTY n, Semiring a) => Semiring (Square n a) where
    zero = pure zero
    (<+>) = liftA2 (<+>)
    one = identity natty
    (<.>) = mul
```

The thing to notice about this implementation is that `zero` and `one` dynamically build matrices of a statically known size, typically based on contextual type information at the call site. They get the runtime representation of that size (a `Natty`) from the `NATTY` dictionary, which the elaborator builds based on the matrix's inferred type.

This is a totally different approach than that of the `reflection` library (which I outlined in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43684733/1523776)). `reflection` is about stuffing explicit runtime values into implicit instance dictionaries, whereas this style takes information that would otherwise only be known at runtime - the size of the matrix - and makes it static, using singletons to make the type information available in the world of values. Of course a real dependently typed language would dispense with the `Natty` ceremony: `n` would be a plain old value and we could use it directly, rather than having to go via a singleton hidden in an instance dictionary.

I'll leave the Kleene algebra stuff to you because I'm lazy and I want to get on to the question of synthesising type information based on runtime input.

---

How can we use these statically sized matrices when we don't know the size statically? You mentioned that your program asks the user how big their graph is (and thus how big the adjacency matrix used to represent the graph is). So the user types a number (a `Nat`-the-value, not `Nat`-the-type) and we're somehow expected to know statically what the user was going to type?

The trick is to write blocks of code which are agnostic to the value of the matrix's size. Then, no matter what the input was, as long as it was a natural number, we know that that block of code will work. We can force a function to be polymorphic using higher-rank types.

```
withNatty :: Nat -> (forall n. Natty n -> r) -> r
withNatty Z r = r Zy
withNatty (S n) r = withNatty n (r . Sy)
```

`withNatty n r` applies the function `r` to the singleton representation of the natural number `n`. `r` has the `Natty n` available at runtime, so it can recover static knowledge of `n` by pattern matching the `Natty`, but `n` can't leak to the outside of the block. (You can also use existential quantification, which is covered briefly in *Hasochism*, to wrap a `Natty` and pass it around. It amounts to the same thing.)

So, for example, supposing we want to print an identity matrix of a dynamically-determined size:

```
main = do
    Just size <- fmap intToNat readLn
    withNatty size (print . mkIdentity)
        where mkIdentity :: Natty n -> Square n Int
              mkIdentity n = natter n one

ghci> main
4
Mat {unMat = (1 :> (0 :> (0 :> (0 :> V0)))) :> ((0 :> (1 :> (0 :> (0 :> V0)))) :> ((0 :> (0 :> (1 :> (0 :> V0)))) :> ((0 :> (0 :> (0 :> (1 :> V0)))) :> V0)))}
```

The same technique applies if you want to, say, build a matrix from a list of lists. This time it's a bit trickier because you have to prove to GHC that all of the lists have the same length, by measuring them.

```
withVec :: [a] -> (forall n. NATTY n => Vec n a -> r) -> r
withVec [] r = r V0
withVec (x:xs) r = withVec xs (r . (x :>))


-- this operation can fail because the input lists may not all be the same length
withMat :: [[a]] -> (forall w h. (NATTY w, NATTY h) => Mat w h a -> r) -> Maybe r
withMat xss r = assertEqualLengths xss (\vs -> withVec vs (r . Mat))
    where assertEqualLengths :: [[a]] -> (forall n. NATTY n => [Vec n a] -> r) -> Maybe r
          assertEqualLengths [] r = Just (r noVecs)
          assertEqualLengths xss@(xs:_) r = withLen xs (\n -> natter n $ r <$> traverse (assertLength n) xss)

          noVecs :: [Vec Z a]
          noVecs = []

          assertLength :: Natty n -> [a] -> Maybe (Vec n a)
          assertLength Zy [] = Just V0
          assertLength (Sy n) (x:xs) = fmap (x :>) (assertLength n xs)
          assertLength _ _ = Nothing

          withLen :: [a] -> (forall n. Natty n -> r) -> r
          withLen [] r = r Zy
          withLen (x:xs) r = withLen xs (r . Sy)

ghci> withMat [[1,2], [3,4]] show
Just "Mat {unMat = (1 :> (2 :> V0)) :> ((3 :> (4 :> V0)) :> V0)}"
ghci> withMat [[1,2], [3]] show  -- a ragged input list
Nothing
```

And if you want to work with square matrices, you have to prove to GHC that the matrix's height is equal to its width.

```
withEqual :: Natty n -> Natty m -> (n ~ m => r) -> Maybe r
withEqual Zy Zy r = Just r
withEqual (Sy n) (Sy m) r = withEqual n m r
withEqual _ _ _ = Nothing

square :: Natty w -> Natty h -> Mat w h a -> Maybe (Square w a)
square = withEqual
```